# How to call multiple functions in an array after a setTimeout between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

Need to create a sequence of functions stored in an array. Need them to be executed every 400ms. Did it by setting 500 `setTimeout(function(){})`'s. Somehow learned that should do it by creating it dynamically. Have the functions ready, but missing the timeouts to make it a nice animation

Here is the part where I think I have to set the timeout's in:

```
function start() {
    mylist.name = this.className;
    mylist.identifier = 'port'+parseFloat(this.id);
    mylist.number = parseFloat(this.id);
    console.log(mylist.number);
    for (var x in todo) {
        todo[x]();
    }
}
```

And here is the array with the functions. Thank you

ps: sorry for bad english, made in Germany :)

```
todo = [

function computer1() {
    $('.'+mylist.name+':eq(1)').css({'background-color': 'chartreuse'});
},
function kabel1() {
    $('.'+mylist.name+':eq(0)').css({'border-bottom-color': 'chartreuse'});
},
function port1() {
    $('#'+mylist.identifier).css({'background-color': 'chartreuse'});
},
function port2() {
    for (var x=0;x<ports;x++) {
        $('#port'+(x+1)).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
        if (x===(mylist.number-1)) {
            $('#port'+(x+1)).css({'background-color': 'chartreuse'});
        }       
    }
},
function kabel2() {
    for (var x=0;x<ports;x++) {
        $('#portugal'+(x+1)+':eq(0)').css({'border-bottom-color': 'blue'});
        if (x===(mylist.number-1)) {
            $('#portugal'+(x+1)+':eq(0)').css({'border-bottom-color': 'chartreuse'});
        }       
    }
},
function device2() {
    for (var x=0;x<ports;x++) {
        $('#'+(x+1)+'device').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
        if (x===(mylist.number-1)) {
            $('#'+(x+1)+'device').css({'background-color': 'chartreuse'});
        }
    }
},
function device3() {
    for (var x=0;x<ports;x++) {
        if (document.getElementById('info').textContent==document.getElementById((x+1)+'device').className) {
            var hammer = document.getElementById((x+1)+'device').getAttribute('class');
            $('.'+hammer+':eq(1)').css({'background-color': 'red'});
        }
    }
},
function mehr() {

}]
```

Comment: Is it in any way possible you could get an executable version of that? Also it is quite a lot of code -> if possible be more specific as this will understandably "turn off" some people ^^ **Please provide minimal example code** :)

Comment: I think you need only the first example part of code to help me, but i dont know maybe you need the complete code for context...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do... create an animation on a canvas... but with multiple functions? Or just an "animation" on an div element?

Comment: No, I want to execute every function every 400ms so every function combined sums up in an animation.

Comment: Because when I start the programm without timeouts, all functions are executed at the same time

Comment: So just just want to execute a list of functions in a row?

Comment: Yes, but with 400ms between execution.

Comment: In the first snippet I iterate throug the list and execute all functions but I need the timeout

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```js
let startTime = new Date().getTime();
let functions = [
    ()=>console.log("f0: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms passed"),
    ()=>console.log("f1: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms passed"),
    ()=>console.log("f2: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms passed"),
    ()=>console.log("f3: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms passed"),
    ()=>console.log("f4: " + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + " ms passed"),
]

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  functions[i]();
  i++;
  if(i > functions.length - 1) i = 0;
}, 400);
```

If it worked always smash the accept button ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in favor of changing the array and modifying synchronous function. Thus changing for loop.

```
// Created variable using let to over come closure
for (let x in todo) {
    setTimeout( ()=> {
        todo[x]();
    }, (x+1)*400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating unnecessary closures or computing specific timeouts

```js
const delay = (ms, x) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))
  
const funcs =
  [ () => console.log (1)
  , () => console.log (2)
  , () => console.log (3)
  ]
  
const forEachDelay = async (ms, [ f = () => {}, ...fs ]) =>
  fs.length === 0
    ? f ()
    : delay (ms, f ()) .then (() => forEachDelay (ms, fs))
    
forEachDelay (1000, funcs)
// 1
// (1000 ms later...) 2
// (1000 ms later...) 3
```

An advantage of using `async` is we get a Promise back and we know when the entire sequence is done –

```
forEachDelay (1000, funcs) .then (() => console.log ('done'), console.error)
// 1
// (1000 ms later...) 2
// (1000 ms later...) 3
// done
```

Promise is an effective data type because it allows you to combine smaller steps into one big-picture step.

Above we write `forEachDelay` using a functional expression, but we could also use an imperative-style `for` loop combined with the powerful `await` syntax –

```js
const delay = (ms, x) =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))
  
const funcs =
  [ () => console.log (1)
  , () => console.log (2)
  , () => console.log (3)
  ]
  
const forEachDelay = async (ms, fs = []) =>
{ for (const f of fs)
    await delay (ms, f ())
}
    
forEachDelay (1000, funcs) .then (() => console.log ('done'), console.error)
// 1
// (1000 ms later...) 2
// (1000 ms later...) 3
// done
```

Comment: You shouldn't make the function `async` if you're not `await`ing anything.

Comment: `async` is used here to guarantee the return of a Promise – otherwise `forEachDelay (1000, [ () => 1 ]) .then (...)` fails because `1` is not a Promise and has no `then`

Comment: Just use `Promise.resolve(f())` then for the base case.